# Spring integration inbound sftp adapter remove unsupprted file with warning message

Tags: spring-integration

I am using inbound sftp adapter in spring integration and works fine. But I have requirement where if client drops file which is not supported then I should print wanring message in log and move that file to someother location or delete it. Is this something supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a [filter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#filter) downstream of the adapter and perform the log/rename/delete on the `discard-channel` flow when a file is rejected by the filter.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your response. I will try this and let you know if it works

Comment: I am still having problem setting discard channel on custom filter which is applied to inbound sftp channel adapter. when you said add filter, how does custom filter will know that all rejected sftp file should go to discard channel? or do you mean by adding message filter before being delivered to transformer which is actually launching my job.

Comment: Sorry Garry for this question but I figured out what do you mean by adding a filter and moving message to disacard channel. This solved my problem.